# World Map with Hotspots for Capitals

Tags: javascript

For an internet site, I am looking for a World map where I could display capitals or metro areas as hotspots/pinpoints. Any to recommend?

What I am looking for is similar to Google Geochart with metro areas:
http://code.google.com/apis/adwords/docs/appendix/metrocodes.html

But Google metro codes are limited to the US, while I also need some World cities (e.g. Beijing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to search for some site that has coordinates for world capitals/large cities.
like here you can get all the capitals' coordinates:
http://www.nobochamp.com/capitals.htm
You can check this site as well:
http://www.world-gazetteer.com/wg.php?x=&men=gcis&lng=en&des=wg&srt=npan&col=abcdefghinoq&msz=1500

You can similarily find some file with all cities with >1mil population and so on.
Then you just create a db with all those places and lat/long pairs and use Google Maps to place  markers on the map.
Now if you need proper heat map with not just points but whole metro areas shown with limits (like whole NYC being red instead of just a marker in the middle of Manhattan), that will be much more complicated as you will need a bunch of shapes for all capitals/large metro areas around the world.

Comment: Very useful links, thanks! For rendering, would you have an alternate option? I just need a high level map with 5-6 worldwide locations, and I am concerned that Google Maps will be an overkill here.

Comment: I have only worked with Google maps and Yahoo, never with Bing. And Google Maps are way better than Yahoo. Frankly, there isn't much choice with GIS APIs and Google is the best option. Plus their API is really extensive and you can implement as many or as few features as possible. Plus there are tons of tutorials available.

Comment: Almost forgot, take a look at Google Fusion tables http://www.google.com/fusiontables/Home - you don't even need to create a db now - you can simply add data to a fusion table and press 'visualize' - and you got a map with all your spots on it. Take a look at any of the public tables there. You can do 'visualize->map and you got yourself a map that you can embed anywhere.